# Execute stored proedure in openquery with parameters

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, openquery

I have a database in SQL Server 2014 and I have a linked server.
i want to run a sp which runs inside her a stored procedure
which belongs to the linked server.

For example I've got the stored proedure :

```
PROCEDURE test (@myint  int) 
AS 
      DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(2000)
      SET @Query = 'INSERT INTO mytable SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([mylinkedserver], ''EXEC  [linkedserverdb].[dbo].[linkedserversp]  
    '+ @myint + '  '')'

       EXEC(@Query)
```

When I'm running the stored proedure `test 42` I'm getting an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'INSERT INTO mytable SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([mylinkedserver], 'EXEC  [linkedserverdb].[dbo].[linkedserversp]  ' to data type int.

Notice that I'm trying to pass the variable myint from my stored proedure to the linkedserver stored proedure which needs that int.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PROCEDURE test (@myint  int) AS 
DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(2000)
SET @Query = 'INSERT INTO mytable SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([mylinkedserver], ''EXEC  [linkedserverdb].[dbo].[linkedserversp]  
'+ CAST(@myint AS VARCHAR(10)) + ''')'

EXEC(@Query)
```

You are trying to concatenate a INT `@myint` with a string `'exec...'` you have to cast `@myint` to a compatible character type e.g. `VARCHAR`.

Comment: I think that i need some type-casting tutorials...:P
Thank you Matt , it's ok

Comment: @Dimitris you are welcome if you are all set please upvote and accept the answer so others know you have gotten what you need and reputation points are awarded.  Thanks